# Is there a separate GitHub repository for the ES2015 modules of OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

I understand that you can get the `ol` package from NPM.

Are the ES2015 modules of OpenLayers 4 auto-generated from the main [openlayers](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers) codebase or is there a separate repository for it? If so, I'd like to fork it please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]** see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/5623

---

I was asking myself the same question.
Until there is a working release you can do the same with the old closure compiler openlayers dist from their GitHub repo.
You need to change the UMD wrapper to do what you want. Look at tasks/build.js and apply following patch or change it yourself.

```
@@ -15,19 +15,10 @@ var generateExports = require('./generate-exports');
 var log = closure.log;
 var root = path.join(__dirname, '..');

-var umdWrapper = ';(function (root, factory) {\n' +
-    '  if (typeof exports === "object") {\n' +
-    '    module.exports = factory();\n' +
-    '  } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {\n' +
-    '    define([], factory);\n' +
-    '  } else {\n' +
-    '    root.ol = factory();\n' +
-    '  }\n' +
-    '}(this, function () {\n' +
-    '  var OPENLAYERS = {};\n' +
-    '  %output%\n' +
-    '  return OPENLAYERS.ol;\n' +
-    '}));\n';
+var umdWrapper = 'var OPENLAYERS = {};\n' +
+    '%output%\n' +
+    '\n' +
+    'export default OPENLAYERS.ol;';

 var version;
```

After the changes you can run

```
make install
make build
```

and the resulting file build/ol.js will contain all the code you want to import. You can use it like this, then:

```
<script type="module">
import ol from './ol.js'; // ← url to ol.js

// do classic ol stuff here :)
</script>
```

But apart from that I don't see a working release yet.

---

If you do want to have a more modular approach. You would have to wait until all modules that openlayers requires are written as ES6 modules or they are finished with the ES6 build. You can transform openlayers sources to import via urls and then you could do stuff like:

```
import olMap from './ol/map.js';
import olTile from './ol/tile/tile.js'; // and so on...
```

I'm not sure how OpenLayers will do it in the end cause the later approach might cause hundreds of requests on your server... not sure if that is the better solution over the bundled then.